# Cannot read property 'query' of undefined, node/mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am getting this error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined at register".

Other posts I looked at seemed to be issues with the DB not connecting properly, but I am getting the console.log message that the db is connected.

```
const { db } = require("../config/db.js");

module.exports = {
    async register(req, res) {
        db.query(
            "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
            [req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password],
            (err, results, fields) => {
                if (!err) {
                    res.send("it worked!");
                } else {
                    console.log("error"); 
                }
            }
        );
    }
};


const mysql = require("mysql");

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "gpsdb"
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        throw(err);
    }
    console.log('connected to db');
});

module.exports = db;
```

It seems like the db is not being exported properly or something but I can't see what's causing the issue. I am basing this off this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZMwg5z5VGk&t=946s   @23 min mark

Comment: To destructure an object, you need an object. `module.exports =  { db };` should work

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. Thank you so much, was driving me insane!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export `db` as an object:

```
module.exports = { db };
```

If you're confused by the syntax, its ES6 syntactic sugar for:

```
module.exports = { db: db };
```